# Apollo client getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, gql

I'm using Apollo Client for my nextJs project. I'm trying to create a storefront Shopify app but i probably not understand how apollo query works.

This is the error:

Server Error
Error: Variable $handle of type String! was provided invalid value.

[product].jsx

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import GET_PRODUCT_BY_HANDLE from '../../lib/graphql/queries/getProductByHandle'
// import GET_PRODUCT from '../../lib/graphql/queries/getProduct'
import { initApollo } from '../../lib/apollo'

// const VARIABLE = 'struccante-oleoso'

export default function Product({ queryByHandle }) {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCT_BY_HANDLE, {
    variables: { handle: queryByHandle },
  })

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

  if (error || !data) return <h2>Error</h2>
  if (data.productByHandle.length === 0) return <h2>404 | Not Found</h2>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <h2>{data.productByHandle.handle}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const queryByHandle = query.productByHandle // if i replace with "struccante-oleoso" works well

  const apolloClient = initApollo()
  await apolloClient.query({
    query: GET_PRODUCT_BY_HANDLE,
    variables: { handle: queryByHandle },
  })
  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
      queryByHandle,
    },
  }
}
```

getProductByHandle.jsx

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'

const GET_PRODUCT_BY_HANDLE = gql`
  query getProductByHandle($handle: String!) {
    productByHandle(handle: $handle) {
      id
      handle
      description
      images(first: 5) {
        edges {
          node {
            url
            altText
          }
        }
      }
      options {
        name
        values
        id
      }
      variants(first: 25) {
        edges {
          node {
            selectedOptions {
              name
              value
            }
            image {
              url
              altText
            }
            title
            id
            price {
              amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
export default GET_PRODUCT_BY_HANDLE
```

apollo.jsx

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'
import { useMemo } from 'react'

const domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN
const storefrontAccessToken =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN

let uri = `https://${domain}/api/2022-10/graphql.json`
let apolloClient

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${uri}`,
      headers: {
        'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': storefrontAccessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    }),
  })
}

export function initApollo(initialState = null) {
  const client = apolloClient || createApolloClient()

  if (initialState) {
    client.cache.restore({
      ...client.extract(),
      ...initialState,
    })
  }
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return client
  }
  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = client
  }
  return client
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  return useMemo(() => initApollo(initialState), [initialState])
}
```

I expect to retrieve handle as a string from gql query

Comment: Inspect `query.productByHandle` - you'll find it's not a string.

Comment: Did you mean to use `query.product` instead?